# Storing values inside while loop using JDBC

Tags: java, while-loop, metadata, teradata, resultset

```
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getSchemas(); 
while(rs.next()) {  
    String DbNames = rs.getString("TABLE_SCHEM");
}
```

I'm trying to store the value of `DbNames` and use it later. I tried using `ArrayList`

```
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getSchemas(); 
ArrayList<String> dbs = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()) {
    dbs.add(rs.getString("TABLE_SCHEM"));
}
for(String[] s : dbs)
{
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
}
```

I'm new to programming and used StackOverflow resources to fix my problem, but I'm still having problems. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: I must caution you, don't fix your code in the question once you know what's wrong with it, let it stay wrong. That way others who view this question will understand what the problem was and why the answers given are appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your ArrayList is a **[raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)** because you have not specified a data type for the ArrayList. Change your ArrayList declaration to a **[generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)** by using

```
ArrayList<String> dbs = new ArrayList<>();
```

That way, when you try to access the values later, they will be `String` instead of `Object`.

Your new code will be

```
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getSchemas();
ArrayList<String> dbs = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()) { 
    dbs.add(rs.getString("TABLE_SCHEM"));
}
for(String s : dbs) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `ArrayList` to save your data retrieved from the result set as below:

```
ResultSet resultset = ;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
while (resultset.next()) {            
    arrayList.add(resultset.getString('TABLE_SCHEM'));
}
```